# How to clear the LogEntries in appium?

Tags: appium, appium-android

In appium this command
`List<LogEntry> logEntries = driver.manage().logs().get("logcat").filter(Level.ALL);` which will return adb logs.

Actually  before perform any click action in my android app i want to clear those adb logs. so how can i do that? and i have already tried hitting command like `adb logcat -c` like below. But its not clearing the data. can anyone help? don't we have any option on appium itself to clear the logs???

```
String[] temp = { "/home/jagadeesh/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb", "logcat", "-c" };
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(temp);
```

Comment: Can you check it manually if it clear the log by running "abd logcat -c" in your terminal and then performing some action in your app? If you can do it manually from terminal then it may be done from appium.

Comment: Yes... i have tried `adb logcat -c` manually from terminal, logs getting cleared. But if i run same command through java then not clearing and same way for appium i didn't found.

Comment: Have you tried calling **List<LogEntry> logEntries2 = driver.manage().logs().get("logcat").filter(Level.ALL);** again after getting the log. This must add new log to logEntries2.

Comment: Not tried. Does it adds new logs to `logEntries2` without previous logs? can you explore more about this?

Comment: First run **adb logcat -c** and then using **logEntries2** might help you.

Comment: `adb logcat -c` not clearing the logs. I tried below code but not clearing.
`String[] temp = { "/home/jagadeesh/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb", "logcat", "-c" };
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(temp);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185477/discussion-between-suban-dhyako-and-jagadeesh).